# Is there an empty character in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

This is my code:

```
reverseEncode :: Char -> String -> Int -> Char
reverseEncode _ [] _ = ?
reverseEncode c (x:xs) offset
 | alphaPos c == (alphaPos x + offset) `mod` 26 = chr (((alphaPos x + offset) + 65) `mod` 26)
 | otherwise = reverseEncode c xs offset
```

It's just a small method used in a virtual Enigma Machine. After writing the function without the second line and testing it, I got this exception:

```
Non-exhaustive patterns in function reverseEncode
```

I then realised I didn't tell the function when to stop recursing. This is how that second line of code was born. Obviously, I could just check the length of the string at each step, but it doesn't look as elegant.

Is there anything in Haskell I can put instead of '?' ? If not, is there anything I can define? Or is this something that could be done in a better way?

EDIT: I've actually tried the version with checking the length of the string, and I get the same exception. So how do I make it work?

Comment: No there is no empty character. Are you sure you do not want to return a `String`?

Comment: I am sure. I have to return the encoded character.

Comment: Consider building a lookup table; then `reverseEncode` is just an application of `lookup` to that table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no empty character. You could however use a character like [the *Nul character* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). For example with:

```
reverseEncode :: Char -> String -> Int -> Char
reverseEncode _ [] _ = '\00'
reverseEncode c (x:xs) offset
    | alphaPos c == sm `mod` 26 = chr ((sm + 65) `mod` 26)
    | otherwise = reverseEncode c xs offset
    where sm = alphaPos x + offset
```

But a more *Haskellish* approach would be to change the return type. For example by using a `Maybe Char` instead. This is often used for "computations that can fail". So we could do this with:

```
reverseEncode :: Char -> String -> Int -> Maybe Char
reverseEncode _ [] _ = Nothing
reverseEncode c (x:xs) offset
    | alphaPos c == sm `mod` 26 = Just (chr ((sm + 65) `mod` 26))
    | otherwise = reverseEncode c xs offset
    where sm = alphaPos x + offset
```

Here the `Nothing` thus means we reached the end of the list without meeting the condition, and `Just x` means that the computation resulted in an answer `x`.

Comment: Okay, so...
The result of this function is used as input to another function. When running the code with your suggested version for reverseEncode, I get an error from the function calling this function, namely " Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘Maybe Char’ ". So basically I have to change the types in every function that calls this function?

Comment: @EmiBuliga: if you use this approach, yes. The `Maybe` type is an instance of `Monad`, so you can use `>>=` to make "chaining" operations more convenient, etc. But that might be a bit "too advanced" for now.

Comment: Of course there's also `(error "This was proven to never happen") :: Char` :-)

Comment: @Bergi since the OP said they were getting a "non-exhaustive patterns" error before putting that line in, I would say it's in fact been proved to happen.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Oh, right, he said "exception". I thought it was linter/compiler warning…